# Finding entities (in a many to many relationship) that are related to other entities

Tags: sql

#### TL;DR problem

> Entity A's have a many to many relationship with Entity B's. Given some Entity B's, how can I find all Entity A's that are related to those given Entity B's?

### Actual Problem

I'm currently a bit stuck on a problem of `SELECT`ing rows that are in a many to many relationship. The problem can be phrased like this:

**Entity A:** `Book`

Each book is stored in a table called `Books` that looks something like this:

```
DESCRIBE Books;
book_id  |   book_name  |  ... other metadata on books
-- book_id is a PRIMARY KEY
```

**Entity B:** `Genres`

A genre of some type, like Adventure or Romance, held in a table like this:

```
DESCRIBE Genres;
genre_id  |  genre_name
-- genre_id is a PRIMARY KEY
```

**Relationship Holder:** `BookGenres`

Each `Entity A`, **Book**, can be related to multiple `Entity B`, **Genre**. For example, Harry Potter can be related to the `genre_names`: 'Adventure' and 'Fantasy'. The relationships are stored here via. a `(book_id, genre_id)` tuple per row

```
DESCRIBE BookGenres;
book_id  |  genre_id
-- book_id REFERENCES Books(book_id)
-- genre_id REFERENCES Genres(genre_id)
-- (book_id, genre_id) is UNIQUE pairing
```

I want to be able to `SELECT` for books that have some desired genres. Let's say, I want to return all `book_id` where the book has the genres 'Adventure' and 'Fantasy'. The best I've been able to do is a self `INNER JOIN` and checking if the pairing ('Adventure', 'Fantasy') exists and returning that `book_id`, but this is terribly slow and if I'm searching for n `genres` relationships, I need n `INNER JOINS`! (unacceptable). My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT t1.book_id
FROM BookGenres as t1
INNER JOIN Genres as t2
ON t2.genre_id = t1.genre_id
INNER JOIN BookGenres as t3
ON t3.book_id = t1.book_id
INNER JOIN Genres as t4
ON t4.genre_id = t3.genre_id
WHERE t2.genre_name = 'Adventure' AND t4.genre_name = 'Fantasy'
```

To search for **Books** that have `n` specified relationships to desired **Genres**, I do `n` self `INNER JOINS` and check if such a pairing exists. This seems forbiddingly inefficient and I would like a bit of help on this query as I'm sure it is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your relationship between Books and Genres is a Many to Many relationship, not a One to Many relationship.

As I understand your question, you want to return a list of all books that match all selected genres. Assuming you want additional information about the book, I have included the Books table

```
SELECT
    Books.book_id
FROM
    Books 
WHERE
    book_id IN (SELECT book_id 
                FROM BookGenres INNER JOIN Genres ON BookGenres.genre_id = Genres.genre_id
                WHERE Genre.genre_name = 'Adventure') AND 
    book_id IN (SELECT book_id 
                FROM BookGenres INNER JOIN Genres ON BookGenres.genre_id = Genres.genre_id
                WHERE Genre.genre_name = 'Fantasy')
```